# Generate random binary matrix with all theirs rows different using numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I need to generate a random binary matrix with dimensions m x n where all their rows are different among themselves. Using numpy I tried

```
import numpy as np
import random
n = 512
m = 1000

a = random.sample(range(0, 2**n), m)
a = np.array(a)
a = np.reshape(a, (m, 1))
np.unpackbits(a.view(np.uint8), axis=1)
```

But it is not suitable for my case because n > 128 and m > 1000. So, the code above generates only rows with at most 62 elements. Could you help me, please?

Comment: `2^512` is an insanely large number Are you sure it is `2**n` and not `2*n` ?

Comment: Also, is `number_of_samples` simply `m`, or some other number? If `number_of_samples` is replaced with `m`, and `2**n` with `2*n` the result is an array with `1000` elements. With `2**n`, the code won't run due to `OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C ssize_t`

Comment: yes, number_of_samples=m. Exactly this is the problem OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C. Maybe another approach should be necessary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could generate a random array of 0's and 1's with [`numpy.random.choice`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.choice.html) and then make sure that the rows are different through [`numpy.unique`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html?highlight=unique#numpy.unique):

```py
import numpy as np

m = 1000
n = 512

while True:
    a = np.random.choice([0, 1], size=(m, n))
    if len(np.unique(a, axis=0)) == m:
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

I would try creating one row at a time and check if that row exists already via a `set` which has a membership testing runtime of O(1). If the row exists simply generate another 1, if not add it to the array and move to the next row until you are done. This principle can be made faster by:

1. Setting the unique `counter` to 0
2. generating `m - counter` rows, adding the unique rows to the solution
3. increasing counter the by unique rows added
4. if `counter == m` you are done, else return to 2

The implementation is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
n = 128
m = 1000
a = np.zeros((m,n))
rows = set()
counter = 0
while counter < m:
    temp = np.random.randint(0, 2, (m-counter, n))
    for row in temp:
        if tuple(row) not in rows:
            rows.add(tuple(row))
            a[counter] = row
            counter += 1
```

### Runtime comparison

By generating all the matrix at once and checking if all the rows are unique you are saving a lot of time, only if n >> log2(m).

**Example 1**
with the following:

```
n = 128
m = 1000
```

I ran my suggestion and the solution mentions in the other answer, resulting in:

```
# my suggestion
17.7 ms ± 328 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
# generating all matrix at once and chacking if all rows are unique
4.62 ms ± 198 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

This is because the probabily of generating `m` different rows is very high in this situation.

**Example 2**
When changing to:

```
n = 10
m = 1024
```

I ran my suggestion and the solution mentions in the other answer, resulting in:

```
# my suggestion
26.3 ms ± 1.36 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

The suggestion of generating all matrix at once and checking if all rows are unique did not finish running. This is because when `math.log2(m) == n` there are exactly `m` valid rows. The probability of generating a valid matrix randomly approaches 0 as the shape of the matrix increases.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a matrix with unique rows and shuffle the rows:

```
n = 512
m = 1000

d = np.arange(m) # m unique numbers
d = ((d[:, None] & (1 << d[:n])) > 0).astype(np.uint8) # convert to binary array
i = np.random.randn(m).argsort() # indices used for shuffling rows
a = d[i] # output
```

all rows are unique:

```
assert len(np.unique(a, axis=0)) == m
```

**Timings**

`n=128, m=1000`:

```
271 µs ± 6.06 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
```

`n=2**10, m=2**14`:

```
50.9 ms ± 2.33 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

This works best for `n <= m`, otherwise you need to swap `d[:n]` with `np.arange(n)`, resulting in longer runtime.